# Testing device dependent code in Ruby

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, minitest

I've used both rspec and minitest for Rails applications and libraries that had straightforward algorithms. By that I mean, if I have

```
def add(a, b)
  a + b
end
```

that's simple to test. I expect that `add(2, 2)` to equal `4`.

But say I have methods dependent on a certain machine.

```
def device_names
  # some code to return an array of device names
end
```

I would get, e.g., `['CPU', 'GPU', 'DSP']`, but this is completely dependent on my machine. No other person would be able to successfully pass the test if I were just expecting that.

How do you handle cross-environment testing as in the second example? How do you make it generic enough to cover that code for testing?

Comment: Corss environment and algorithmic are different things. It is not clear which of them you are asking.

Comment: @sawa, sorry, I've edited my initial post to make it clear I'm asking about cross-environment testing.

Answer (score 1):

The piece of code in `device_names` method probably calls some methods in other Ruby classes and results of those calls are then manipulated by your code. You can stub those calls and test your method in isolation.

Here's a (silly) example of how to create a stub on any instance of a String class:

`String.any_instance.stub(:downcase).and_return("TEST")`

Now any call to `downcase` on any instance of String will return "TEST". You can play with that in `irb`:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'rspec/mocks'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> RSpec::Mocks::setup(self)
=> #<RSpec::Mocks::Space:0x10a7be8>
irb(main):003:0> String.any_instance.stub(:downcase).and_return("TEST")
=> #<RSpec::Mocks::AnyInstance::StubChain:0x10a0b68 @invocation_order={:stub=>[nil], :with=>[:stub], :and_return=>[:wit
, :stub], :and_raise=>[:with, :stub], :and_yield=>[:with, :stub]}, @messages=[[[:stub, :downcase], nil], [[:and_return,
"TEST"], nil]]>
irb(main):004:0> "HAHA".downcase
=> "TEST"
```

Of course, you can also stub methods in single instances, for specific parameters, and so on. Read more on [stubbing methods](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-12/docs/method-stubs).

Now that you know what will be returned by the platform specific code, you can test your method and always get expected results.

Comment: This is definitely in the direction I was looking for. I didn't know it was called stubbing. I'm using Ruby FFI to call some C functions that return pointers to device memory. I don't think stubbing will work in this instance since now there's other methods dependent on a valid pointer for a specific device.